# Link for mobile layout is extremely hard to press

Tags: feature-request, chat, footer

I just recently bought the new version of Nexus 7 and went to the chat. It didn't detect me as a mobile user so I thought I'd press the mobile link in the bottom bar, but it's *extremely* hard to do as it is so small (4x1 ***millimeters*** is nowhere near reasonable). Zooming in on the page hides the link completely as it overflows to the right and off the screen. I cannot scroll there so it's a bit difficult to get anything done.

Could the link be made bigger or some other solution found to this issue?

And I'm not requesting the desktop site on purpose:
[image: Use desktop version unticked]

(*Käytä sivuston... [työpöytäversiota]* translates to *Use the desktop version of the site*)

This is how it looks like when zoomed in:
[image: on Chrome]
[image: on Firefox]

Comment: In all fairness the fullsize version of the site isn't supposed to be used on mobiles (although I do all the time because [...tails off into rant])

Comment: @RichardTingle come on, now we're curious!

Comment: Why would zooming in cause anything to reposition? Sounds like a terrible browser. o.o When I zoom in, it does just that - zoom in.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd To be honest it's largely just to access things which aren't available on mobile; progress of my flags, tag wikis and such, my rant was redacted largely because it was dull. **But now you must suffer its full dullness for all time!**

Comment: @animuson Google Chrome.

Comment: @RichardTingle it automatically throws me to the full version

Comment: @3ventic open the options menu and deselect "Request Desktop Site"!

Comment: @Flyk Not selected.

Comment: @3ventic I'm using Chrome on my Android phone and it does not exhibit this behavior. They must have a buggy version out or something.

Comment: @animuson You're using a phone, I'm on a tablet.

Comment: @3ventic The behavior should still be the same. Zooming in should just zoom in - it shouldn't reposition anything, and Stack Exchange shouldn't need to account for a browser repositioning things during a zoom. That just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @animuson Firefox does it too

Comment: Try going to the [chat main page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) the zoom might work better in there.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The main page zooms fine but I don't see how that helps the actual chat page...

Comment: @3ventic if you choose "mobile" in the main chat page then go to a chat room, doesn't it retain the mobile view?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Oh, that's one workaround :)